# PHP Zend_date inserting now() into db

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am creating a web app using php and zend framework and trying to insert a new row to database using this code :

```
class PriceWatcher_PriceTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

protected $_name = 'price_watcher_price';
public function newPrice($data)
{
    $data['tme']=Zend_Date::now();
    $this->insert($data);
}}
```

I have column in my db called `tme` with `datetime` format. when I upload this piece of code on server, it works perfectly but when trying to run locally it stores

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

I checked mysql log for queries and found this query :

> UPDATE `price_watcher_price` SET `tme`='2014-48-30 10:48:42' WHERE (`id`='40')

Watching carefully at the query, you can see that it sends `minute` in stead of `month` in date string and mysql rejects it.
And something more strange is that when I `echo` it, I get this:

> Jan 30, 2014 11:07:08 AM

And here month is OK.Something important is that my server is linux and my local system is windows.
 Where is the problem?

Comment: you want to insert or update ??

Comment: No difference.both inserts and  updates for date failed.I found the solution and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self. In your `Bootstrap.php` put add code below to function `_init_Loader_Autoloader`:

```
date_default_timezone_set ( 'Asia/Tehran' );
$locale = new Zend_Locale ( 'fa_IR' );
Zend_Registry::set ( 'Zend_Locale', $locale );
```

If you dont have that function create it and put the code in it. change  `Asia/Tehran` and `fa_IR` to your own time zone.In my case I had to use them.
You can see list of php time zones [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).
You can see list of zend_locales [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.locale.appendix.html).

Thanks for your helps.